# Importing a Collada file in Papervision 3d

Tags: flash, actionscript, papervision3d, collada, 3dsmax

I am having trouble importing a Collada file in Papervision3d. I have done an exhaustive Google search to no avail. All the examples and tutorials end with errors, be they "Can't find materials" errors or simply not showing the file at all. I have tried many different types of Collada files, including a lot of Collada's own from their testing library. Basically, I just want to know an updated way for loading a Collada file into flash with Papervision 3d 2.0 (Great White).

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using 3dsMax you'll need to get a plugin to export the collada file.  The default export doesn't work properly.  If you're using 3dsMax 2009, you'll need a special version of the plugin.

I believe that this is it:
http://www.flashbookmarks.com/pv3dchat/ColladaMax2009.zip

Once you know that your dae file is correct, you'll need to build a MaterialsList object with each of the materials that your 3D file will use. It's a bit of work but after you've done that everything should be good.  Make sure the name of your materials in the MateriasList are the same as they are in your 3d program.  They'll be mapped to the 3d object by their name.

Answer (score 0):

```
cow = new Collada("http://papervision2.com/wp-content/downloads/dae/cow.dae");
scene.addChild(cow);
```

You can use your local model. Just don't forget to create a camera and point it on your model. Also don't forget to "addChild". + try playing with models Scale, it probably can be too big to fit the screen.